How to scrape flutter/dart dynamic renderer website where inspecting web element is not allowed
I am scrapping a website which has many list items and buttons web lements contents getting displayed through the dynamic rendering of the flutter/dart website.
I tried to approximate the button position and used pyautogui to click on various elements but this solution won't work when there any many buttons/elements to find.
Sharing the source code of the dynamic webpage I am scrapping in the attachment below.
Can anyone help with this in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Can you share the locator used? Also, did you try accessing the shadow dom for the locator chosen?

pyautogui has function to find button using its image.

image shows line #shadow-root which may need to use ShadowRoot() in selenium (or similar command in JavaScript)

Flutter doesn't render as regular HTML elements, but rather through a custom WebGL engine (more details in the documentation) that turns the Flutter UI into actual pixel data. Thus, the usual web-scraping techniques that rely on the DOM simply won't work. As I see it, there are only a few (somewhat) viable ways to scrap a Flutter-based app:

Analyze the network activity with the developer tools of your browser of choice, and reverse-engineer the data you need from there. If the data is dynamic, it's highly unlikely the Flutter app itself is changing whenever the data changes, but rather it must be pulling the information from somewhere. If you analyze the requests done by the app carefully, you might hit the endpoint with the things you want.
If the Flutter app is embedded into the site, the relevant data might be passed into the app during loading. It might be useful to read how Flutter web embedding works, identify the loading script in your target site and check if anything useful is being passed during loading.
If you're really desperate, remember that you can pull the canvas as an image and apply some image processing magic to traverse the app into the info you need. This is already outside my abilities, but technically doable.
Finally, consider that Flutter doesn't obfuscate much during web compilation, it only minifies the application. This means that, technically, you can reverse engineer the entire application, which you could automate to download the app -> execute a decompilation script -> extract the info you need. There's not a lot of knowledge or tooling on how to do this with Flutter, and even with a more popular framework I'd consider this a daunting task, so I can't recommend this idea. Here's an interesting article on the topic.

Best of luck!
